# how do i display a different page using the browser?

Tags: angular

New to angular. I noticed that by default the app.component.html is displayed when we first create an angular project and view on on localhost:4200/ 
I learned in a tutorial that in order to make another page, lets say an "Explore Page" similar to how instagram how an explore page, I would create the page as a component.

My Question is, now that i created that explore page component, how would I display that site on the browser? 
without using routing or having to go through the initial page first

[image]

Comment: would you like it so that instead of the app.component showing as the first page, you'd want it to be explore-page.component?

Comment: @jeffreyrampineda yes exactly. explore-page.component.html has the code of a full page. I want to see this explore page instead of the index.html.

Comment: you can go to the index.html file just outside the app/ folder and replace the <app-root> selector to <app-explore-page> selector. See answer at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Without using routing, if you want to display a component, you can use its **selector**

Sample:

```
// src/app/app.component.html
<app-explore-page></app-explore-page>
```

or

```
// src/index.html
...
<body>
    <app-explore-page></app-explore-page>
</body>

// src/app/app.module.ts
...
bootstrap: [ExplorerPageComponent]
```